# Best stack options for Video Chat server using GAE/Java and Flash

Tags: google-app-engine, video-streaming, chat, video-capture

We want to build a high performance web based Chat server using Flash on client side and Java on the server side on Google App Engine.

We want to ignore other options like Silverlight, HTML5 for now.

Client side:
So on the client side we have Flash. We probably write some action script code to start using the web cam and posting it to a web server. Please correct me if i am wrong.

The Server side:
OPTIONS:
1) Adobe Flash Media Server - i cant figure out what this is and whether this can be integrated with Java code on GAE?

2) Wowza for Google AppEngine
Seems like a dead end.. http://www.wowzamedia.com/forums/showthread.php?t=5009

3) Wowza for amazon - If we can Integrate this with GAE App that would be cool.

4) Red5 - Any commercial hosting that is reliable?

Any pointers, case studies, advice will be really helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

GAE is probably not a good fit for this application since you can't have long-running server processes.  See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273362/how-to-achieve-interrupt-driven-communication-from-server-to-client-with-servlets/3277785#3277785) to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273362/how-to-achieve-interrupt-driven-communication-from-server-to-client-with-servlets).

Is the chat going to just be between users?  Why not let them connect to each other directly (this is how Chatroulette works)?

Comment: Chatroulette looks great, do you have an idea who this can be done?

Comment: I googled about it and found that it works using Adobe stratus etc.. I will digg a bit more to see whether I can make this work and finally integrate into GAE/J.
Thanks for your inputs.